# updated color code not showing in magento frontend

Tags: magento, caching, updates

we are devoloping magento site.

when we update the code in magento site, it's not displaying in frontend.

cache has been cleared, but still some  colors are not updating.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flush magento cache and storage cache. If you are using apc or varnish cache you must be refresh. If not worked then you need to change your css file with new name and give new css file name in your xml file.